# Apply CSS class to HTML Action Link in Razor

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.actionlink

I have the following HTML code:

```
<li>
  <a href="dashboard.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
</li>
```

The Code displays the menu item as the following image:

[image]

I want to replace the link with `@Html.ActionLink` in Razor code, I try this:

```
<li>
  <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw">@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Index", "Home")</i>
</li>
```

But unfortunately it displays the menu item as:

[image]

I also tried:

```
<li>
   @Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "fa fa-dashboard fa-fw" })
</li>
```

The style overrides the text font and displays the result as:

[image]

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: `Html.ActionLink()` renders a text only between the `<a>` tags and cannot be used to render child tags. You can use `Url.Action()` to generate the url (another option is to render the `<i>` and `ActionLink()` and use a bit of css (positioning) but its a bit ugly). Finally, if this is something you use repeatedly, you could create your own extension method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<li>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Dashboard", "Home")">
        Dashboard <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> 
    </a>
</li>
```